# Next 13.4 data fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this ugly function:

```
export const getFilesFromFirebase = async () => {
  const fileRef = ref(storage, `PDF/`);
  const files = await listAll(fileRef);

  const filesDetails = await Promise.all(
    ...//some code to get an array of files
  );

  return filesDetails;
};
```

Inside of a serverActions.ts file, that is being called in a server side page as follows:

```
const AccountPage = async () => {
  const filesList: FileList = await getFilesFromFirebase();

//lots of code that don't matter much now
}
```

**My questions is, without the useEffect hook, how can I fetch the data from firebase every time I go to AccountPage?**

I tried to follow the docs, but no success...
[doc1](https://I%27ve%20checked%20the%20docs%20but%20no%20success...%20https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-third-party-libraries)
[doc2](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#fetchcache)